# Problems with the responsive boxes

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm having problem with the boxes in responsive. I have three buttons. After clicking on the button displays a detail box. I want to show button and detail box in a row for each box on small resolution.

**Now**: button, button, button; detail, detail, detail;

**And I want**: button - detail; button - detail; button - detail

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <a class="tab1" href="#">first</a>
    <a class="tab2" href="#">second</a>
    <a class="tab3" href="#">third</a>
</div>

<div class="box detail1">
    <div>detail 01</div>
</div>
<div class="box detail2">
    <div>detail 02</div>
</div>
<div class="box detail3">
    <div>detail 03</div>
</div>
```

Here is the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/izmy666/xnyydvb6/

Do you know a solution? Or is the best solution duplicate buttons for each box and show only on small resolution (and hide original buttons)?

Thank you for any advice or recomendations !

Comment: do you mean the button and box beside each other or on the next row of another?

Comment: I want on normal resolution in first row three buttons and second row detail  boxes. In responsive resolution (@media screen and (max-width: 600px)) I want on each separate row: button first - detail 01 - button second - detail 02 - button third - detail 03.

Comment: then you have to duplicate and hide original buttons already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your html to be one after another

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <a class="tab1" href="#">first</a>
    <div class="box detail1">
        <div>detail 01</div>
    </div>
    <a class="tab2" href="#">second</a>
    <div class="box detail2">
        <div>detail 02</div>
    </div>
    <a class="tab3" href="#">third</a>

<div class="box detail3">
    <div>detail 03</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and under `.box` add `float:left;`. this will attain the results you want. I've saved the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/xnyydvb6/3/

The float left will ensure that the elements are directly after one another.

Comment: No, I want this just in responsive resolution (@media screen and (max-width: 600px)). In normal resolution I want first three buttons and after that detail boxes.